# How to get time difference in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have current time data and future time data which I get in `nexTime` variable and convert it to date. I need to subtract the current time from `tempDate` (future time), I do it through the subtract method, but I run into a problem that the result is `1970`. Tell me, how can I subtract the current time from the future time to get the difference?

```
      var timeNowMS = (DateTime.now()).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      var timenowSeconds = (timeNowMS / 1000).round();
      DateTime tempDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").parse(
          "${timeNow.year}-${timeNow.month}-${timeNow.day} ${nexTime as String}");
      final Duration timeNowDuration = Duration(seconds: timenowSeconds);
      final DateTime drive = tempDate.subtract(timeNowDuration);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a method that calculates `Duration` from two dates
an example :

```
DateTime date1 = /* your first date */
DateTime date2 = /* your other date */

Duration diff = date2.now().difference(date1);
```

it will generate a `Duration` with the duration between the two dates

and If you want to get a `DateTime` after adding a `Duration` to a previous date, use :

```
    DateTime dateAfterAddinOneDay = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1));
```

so as today is 2022-10-12, the dateAfterAddinOneDay will be 2022-10-13

Comment: Thank you very much, but can you tell me what to do if I need to add more time, how can I do this?

Comment: there is an add method that applies on the DateTime, I will update my answer